# Custom exception handling of JWT validations - how to approach?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

still relatively new to Springboot/JWTs here so apologies for lack of understanding.

Hit a bit of a brick wall in approach to handling invalid JWTs. For some background the project is Springboot 3, utilizing Spring Security 6. I am able to handle most exceptions well and return legible http responses for them, but I can't seem to do it for the SignatureException class in io.jsonwebtoken.security. The error will throw the following message:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
```

This error is occuring during the filterInternal method when a completely invalid token is sent with Bearer Authorization, I expect it to act similarly to an actual expired token and throw the same error response, but it doesn't:

```
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException, AuthException {
        String jwt = parseJwt(request);

        if (jwt != null)
        {
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt)) **<- Will throw the error**
            {
                System.out.println("Token is expired");
                handleAuthorisationDenied(response, "Unauthorised access: Security token expired");
                return;
            }
```

I've tried catching the exception in my JWTService class as well as within the filter itself, but haven't figured out how to. Just for clarity this is the method in my AuthFilter (doFilterInternal class) that I am calling on:

```
    private void handleAuthorisationDenied(HttpServletResponse response, String message) throws IOException {
        ApiError errorResponse = new ApiError(
                HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                message);

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorResponse));
    }
```

I've also tried making Optional.of(jwt).orElseThrow(...) in some of my methods within the JWT service that are causing the errors - still doesn't work.

Anyone experienced something similar or can anyone see where my logic is faltering when approaching this task? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i would suggest you remove your entire implementation and actually implement the handling of JWTs in accordance to how the documentation actually recommends you to implement it. Spring Security has had JWT support for the "resource server" specification in the Oauth2 rfc which handles incoming JWT tokens, since 2017, and you should not follow bad blogs/tutorials that don't themselves read the spring docs. https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

Comment: I didn't realise the Resource Server specification was useful for stateless applications and thought this approach was correct - I will have to look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `I didn't realise the Resource Server specification was useful for stateless applications` what did you think it was used for? it was design specifically for stateless applications and scalability. That was the entire point of it!

Comment: I think just a general lack of understanding on my part led me to believe that the Oauth2 approach required authentication persistence - I can see now from the flow diagrams that assumption was incorrect. I'm relieved to see the solution is so simple.